# drupal batch fails to copy (some) files

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-batch

I have a working drupal batch process. In it I want to copy image files (JPGs) from a source directory into a target directory with PHP copy function. Both the directories exist. The source file does exist, too. But the copy does not succeed.

I checked for the file permissions of the source directory (0755) and the source file (0744) and the target directory (0755). The owner and group are that of the script.

I debugged by putting the success of the copy into watchdog. It says it was successfull. But the file is not there.

This is the code where the copy takes place

```
$copy_from = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".$file->filepath;
$copy_to = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".$path_new;


$success = false;
if (file_exists($copy_from)) {
    $success = copy($copy_from, $copy_to);
    watchdog('catalog_copy2', ($success ? 'yes' : 'no') 
      . ' | ' . "copy('{$copy_from}', '{$copy_to}')");
}
```

If I copy the watchdog output and edit it slightly to end up in an shell copy order

```
cp path/to/file dest_path
```

The file is copied with no fuzz at all. So no typos and no case sensitive issues are in order.

I'm clearly nearly out of my mind, because I do not understand why I cannot copy the files with PHP.

Strange thing though is, some of the files **are** copied with my batch and some are not.

I'd be grateful for any hint where to look for to find a solution.

---

### edit

I've worked around the problem by using the shell `cp` command using php's `exec` command. I'm not happy with this, but I had to make it work.

---

### edit

I circumvented the problem by using the API function from the file_field module

Comment: Look into the error log why this failed. See as well http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php - everything else is sitting in the dark.

Comment: the copy function returns TRUE, so there is no error, is it?

Comment: @hakre no error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was not solved, but I managed to use the API functions from the file_field modules which works perfectly